Injective envelope of B(H)
$B(\ell^2)$ is an injective operator system by a result of Arveson. However, $B(\ell^2)$ is not an injective Banach space, since it is not linearly isomorphic to a $C(K)$ space (for instance, $C(K)$ spaces have metric approximation property whereas $B(\ell^2)$ does not by Szankowski).
Let $C(M)$ be the Banach space injective envelope of $B(\ell^2)$.

Q: Is there a description of $M$, akin to the projective cover of the Cantor set in the literature?

For example, the projective cover of the Cantor set corresponds to the unique countable atomless Boolean algebra (up to isomorphisms)

"the projective cover of the Cantor set corresponds to the unique countable atomless Boolean algebra (up to isomorphisms)", no it is not the projective cover, Cantor set is just the Stone space of this algebra (the Lindenbaum algebra). Note that projective compact spaces are precisely the extremally disconnected ones.
For a Banach space $X$, isn't the injective envelope just $C(G(B_{X^{}})$, where $G$ stands for the Gleason cover. If so, for $B(\ell_2)$, as the dual ball of weak-separable by the Banach-Alaoglu, you will likely get $C(G({0,1}^{\mathbb N})$.

If what I say about the Gleason cover is true, I can probably figure out the details.

@TomaszKania Apologies for poor wording on my part; the correspondence is by completion. The injective envelope of a Banach space $X$ is $C(G(A))$, where $A\subseteq X^*$ is a minimal boundary in the sense of CohenLacey1969 https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(69)90019-6. So a side question is: what is a minimal boundary of $B(\ell^2)$? Perhaps it'd be much more interesting to pose this question for $B(X)$ for a general Banach space $X$.
